# Imprimir com setInterval no mesmo lugar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, front-end

Preciso que quando o "preenchendo..." for imprimido pelo `setInterval`, seja exatamente no mesmo lugar da primeira impressão. Acontece que está indo para baixo ou para frente. Há como fazer isso, imprimir várias vezes no mesmo lugar em 3 e 3 segundos sem sair ali do `border`?

```js
var x = setInterval(function(){

$('div').append('<p id="demo1">Preenchendo...</p>')

}, 1000)
```

```css
#demo{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>


<span><h4>Espaço em branco</h4></span>
<div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vem vez de `append` use `html`. E para que seja de 3 em 3 segundos, basta definir o intervalo para `3000`. Veja:

```js
var x = setInterval(function() {

  $('div').html('<p id="demo1">Preenchendo...</p>')

}, 1000)
```

```css
#demo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

  <span><h4>Espaço em branco</h4></span>
  <div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```